# Prove that $x^p-x^{p-1}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Since this polynomial $f(x)=x^p-x^{p-1}+1$ is relative prime to its derivative, it is separable. Can I prove irreducibility from here? Can anyone give me some hints to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see how to deduce this from the fact that $x^p-x+1$ is irreducible? If so, that question has been asked here a number of times...

Comment: @Lubin : Yes Yes... I understand..

Comment: I know that $x^p-x+1$ is irreducible but I did not see how to deduce from there. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: In general, if $a_nx^n\dots a_0$ is irreducible with $a_n,a_0\neq 0$, then so is $a_0x^n+\dots a_n$ - the reverse.

Comment: I don't know about this. But now I know it! Thanks!!

Comment: To make sure: if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then $x^pf(1/x)=x^pg(1/x)h(1/x)$. In the r.h.s. you get two polynomials by splitting that $x^p$ in the obvious way. This proves the result mentioned by Thomas.